# send message with EventEmitter to observable and send message EventEmitter next from observable subscription, not destroying

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using classes and components. On component destroy, calling classes to destroy method and making unsubscribe next to destroy classes related observable.

I am using Inline Event Emitter as an event and sending a message to observable next. So where observable is subscribing there I'm updating some data and sending next to eventEmitter whatever received in observable subscription in the message.

for example:
class 3 sending observable(emitmessage), either or both class2 and class1 subscribing observable(sent from class3) and sending next to emit message(event emitter of the message).

here is the sample code

```js
class1:
-------
  export class1 {
    unsubscribe = new Subject();
    mydata1;
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
      this.myService.getFormComponentInstance$.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe((modelData: any) => {
        ( < EventEmitter < any >> modelData.Event).next(this.mydata1);
      })

    }

    destroyUtil() {
      this.unsubscribe.next();
      this.unsubscribe.complete();
    }
  }

class2:
-------
  export class2 {
    mydata2
    unsubscribe = new Subject();
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
      this.myService.getFormComponentInstance$.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe((modelData: any) => {
        modelData.PayLoad = this.mydata2;
        ( < EventEmitter < any >> modelData.Event).next(modelData);
      })
    }

    destroyUtil() {
      this.unsubscribe.next();
      this.unsubscribe.complete();
    }
  }

class3:
  export class3 {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    onSomeEvent() {
      let data = null;
      this.someMethod(data);
    }

    someMethod(data) {
      let modelEvent = {
        PayLoad: data,
        Event: new EventEmitter()
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.myService.getFormComponentInstance$.next(modelEvent)
      });

      return modelEvent.Event;
    }
  }

component1:
-----------
  utilInstance;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.utilInstance = new class1();
    ...
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.utilInstance.destroyUtil();
    this.utilInstance = null;
  }
  MyService
  ---------
  someMethod(data) {
    let modelEvent = {
      PayLoad: data,
      Event: new EventEmitter()
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myService.getFormComponentInstance$.next(modelEvent)
    });

    return modelEvent.Event;
  }
}
othercompnents:
---------------
  myservice.someMethod(data).subscribe((res) => ....);
```

So I'm facing issues like observables `getFormComponentInstance` are not getting destroyed. On repeat it's processed, subscription getting an increase.

Please suggest to me where I making mistake. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: in `ngOnDestroy` why don't you just destroy the instance? `this.utilInstance = null`?

Comment: @Bargros sorry i forgot to add that one already i m using....but eventhough is not destroying